# ML Kit Barcode Scanning - which image format to use with FirebaseVisionImageMetadata?

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

The [documentation for ML Kit's barcode scanning functionality](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/read-barcodes) says you should configure a `FirebaseVisionImageMetadata` like in the snippet below:

```
FirebaseVisionImageMetadata metadata = new FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
        .setWidth(1280)
        .setHeight(720)
        .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
        .setRotation(rotation)
        .build();
```

The documentation is on what format to use is completely absent. And [the API doc for the ImageFormat interface](https://firebase.google.cn/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/common/FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ImageFormat) is not really helpful.

How am I supposed to know what to choose here? What will the consequences be of choosing one of the other? Do devices differ in which formats are supported?

Answer (score 0):

Supported file formats are in the [FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ImageFormat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/common/FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.ImageFormat) section of the documentation.

Specifically its [YV21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YV12) or [NV21](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#NV21) (links go to Android documentation)

As you can see with the Android docs, its mainly about which camera library you are using as to which format is recommended.

The format determines how the image data is represented in the `ByteBuffer` you pass, so if you use one which does not match the source the image will be interpreted incorrectly. If you're not using a `ByteBuffer`, you don't need to create the metadata object!